# What are these A2 and A3 stickers?

Tags: travel

I just read the manga [*travel*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Travel.html?id=g_OOMQAACAAJ) by Yuichi Yokoyama.

What is the meaning of the A2 and A3 stickers seen on packages and documents carried by strangers when the 3 main characters walk inside the train? A3 is on small tubes, and A2 is on a folder and an A4-sized box, so I guess it is not ISO 216 (paper size) though.

This manga contains zero dialogs and nearly zero text of any kind, except for A3 and A2, which are shown prominently.

[image: A3 on page 30] | [image: A2 on page 31]

<sup>Left: A3 stickers on page 30 | Right: A2 sticker on page 31</sup>

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are talking about, since I cannot spot anything in that image, but since you are talking about documents it might simply be their size as explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_216).

Comment: Sorry I don't have any image of the page showing B2 and A2. B2 is on small tubes, and A2 is on a folder and a A4-sized box, so I guess it is not ISO 216 though...

Comment: I just finished readin... err, viewing the scenes in this manga. However, I replaced B2 with A3 because that's what I found instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's true that this manga lacks any dialogs, there are actually 2 pages at the end (pg. 196-197) that describe the whole scenes from the beginning until the end.

For page 30-31,

[image: pg. 30-31]

> **30-31** 鞄の中にファクシミリ用感熱紙、コピー用紙、ファイルブックなどの文具又は書類が覗いている。
>
> **30-31** Thermal papers for facsimile, copy paper, filing book and other stationaries or documents are peeking through the bag.

Researching those things returned these images:

[image: thermal paper for facsimile] [image: copy papers]

<sup>Thermal papers for facsimile by Fujifilm | Copy papers by Super Echo</sup>

Thus, I believe [spiel's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7455/what-are-these-a2-and-a3-stickers#comment8858_7455) was actually right: **they are standard paper size labels**. The A3 thermal papers are rolled into a cylinder, and the A2 copy papers are showing their shorter side. (Which means that the filing book is also A2-size, [which also exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr3tg.png))